# Calling a script with program files

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd

I am trying to call a script that is located in program files but it wont work...I believe the problem is in the fact that it doesn't recognize the directory "Program Files" but I don't know how to solve this very basic mistake.

```
ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Scripts\bin\scriptmgr", "--dts" + filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a missing space?

```
ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Scripts\bin\scriptmgr", "--dts " + filename);
                                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an environment variable such as

```
        ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"%programfiles%\Scripts\bin\scriptmgr\" + fileName);
        pInfo.Arguments = "--dts";
        Process.Start(pInfo);
```

and using `ProcessStartInfo` to specify the arguments/other variables

Comment: When I try typing in %programfiles%\Scripts\bin\scriptmgr directly into the command prompt it still gives me "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

Comment: When typing "cd %programfiles%" it gives you not recognized?

Comment: cd works but I cannot execute a program by typing it that way